# best way to cache dynamic tastypie resource? memche,redis,joblib or any other in memory

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, tastypie

I am currently working a django/tastypie web app.I have a dynamic resource, which is based on one of my python module, which will return data like this

```
{
'company_code_1': {'indicator1': 1000, 'indicator2':'Name1'},
'company_code_2': {'indicator1': 150, 'indicator2':'Name2'}
}
```

depends upon the loged in users preference we will send limited company and limited indicators.

Problem now is we are calculating the values each and every time when the user hit the api.

Now, i want to avoid the repetitive calculation by implementing cache. But i am confused which cache to use. Please suggest a way.

Comment: Please write down the detail point you're confused about. Otherwise it's hard to answer.

Comment: I am not too familiar with caching ! i want to execute a particular function every 2 minute and have it in cache ! later when retriving the result i want to send limited data based on users's preference. We have around 5000 companies and 200+ indicators. We will limit company wise and indicator wise. What I am confused is all of them talking abo ut fetching value for a particular key (means vertically) we need horizontally too. @okm

Comment: have you tried this ? http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/caching.html

Comment: @boltsfrombluesky Yes. But, it doesn't support my use case. Since I have dynamic resource. I will serve different results for each user. I am not sure whether my implementation is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/ 
It should give you a nice overview of best practices.

Comment: i have come across this ! but couldnt find anyway to do it dynamically!

Comment: I'm still unclear on what it is that's supposed to be dynamic.